# How to find out the state of a Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to get the text from a java.util.regex.Matcher? It seems to be write-only. There's method to set it (`reset(CharSequence input)`), but no getter (unless I'm overlooking it). There's also a method for getting the pattern (`pattern()`), but the text is private without any getter. Why?

Is there a way to find out if a match was attempted other then calling e.g. `group()` and catching the `IllegalStateException`?

I'm asking this because I'm using a `Matcher` as a member and don't want to repeat the information in additional members, as it clobbers the class needlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation shows, you're right : there is no way to get the text from the matcher or to know if a matching operation has been executed.

You could encapsulate the matcher inside a custom rusable class holding the state for you :

```
public class StatefulMatcher {

    private Matcher matcher;
    private CharSequence input;
    private boolean matchDone;

    public StatefulMatcher(Pattern pattern, String input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    }

    public void reset(CharSequence input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.matcher.reset(input);
        this.matchDone = false;
    }

    public boolean matches() {
        matchDone = true;
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public boolean isMatchDone() {
        return matchDone;
    }

    public CharSequence getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Comment: This is the best thing I could do, but I'm really not happy about this. I wanted to simplify my class a bit, and creating an addition class with many methods does not make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should be able to call

```
Matcher m = ...;
m.pattern().pattern();
```

And it doesn't work?

Comment: This returns the String used in `Pattern.compile(s)`, but I want the one used in `pattern.matcher(s)`.

Comment: It is strange what you want to do. However, I would wrap the Matcher in a Wrapper-class containing the String and the Matcher.

Comment: Why is it strange??? I'm using a `Matcher` as member of my class, the matcher remembers it's `text`, and you think it's strange if I want to avoid remembering it separately?

Comment: The Matcher class is obviously not a string wrapper/container, I do not see the reason for saving it as a member. I would save the String, then compile the pattern when needed. But of course I do not know how often you need to use the Matcher...

Comment: I need the Matcher from the very beginning to the end. I need the String when something goes wrong, and I'd prefer to get it out of the Matcher.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get IllegalStateException, because you're trying to do something in the middle of the matcher?

This is from the API
"The explicit state of a matcher is initially undefined; attempting to query any part of it before a successful match will cause an IllegalStateException to be thrown. The explicit state of a matcher is recomputed by every match operation."

Comment: I'm using the matcher in several methods. If some conditions fails, I want to provide the detailed information about what happened, including the match position and the (un)matched String. Some conditions get tested before the first match attempt.